# Slow Magento 2 saving for configurable products

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

when I save a Simple Product it goes through quite fast. When I do a Configurable product with lots of associated Simple Products as options, it takes a whole lot of time to save (20+ seconds).

Magento is currently in production mode with all products indexed by a cron job.

Is there a way to make this faster? I think that it might be saving all Simple Products associated with the Configurable product, which is making it slow. Can it maybe be set to save only the particular Simple Product?

Comment: Related : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6167